# How can node-gyp build be made verbose?

Tags: node-gyp

I would like to see compiler and linker flags being used while my node binding is getting built. How can I make `node-gyp build` run in verbose mode to achieve that. (similar to `make VERBOSE=1` for `cmake`)

Comment: Are you installing with `npm install --verbose ...` ?

Answer (score 14):

Try

```
node-gyp rebuild --verbose
```

Answer (score 5):

`make V=1` helps me to have verbose `V8` build. I didn't try `node.js`.

I don't know `gyp` very well, but I know it writes to `out/Makefile`, at the begging of `Makefile`

```
# The V=1 flag on command line makes us verbosely print command lines.
ifdef V
  quiet=
else
  quiet=quiet_
endif
```

Comment: setting V=1 seems to help.  If running `node-gyp` indirectly (through npm), this can be done by `export V=1` prior to running npm.